# How do you print two items on the same line in lisp?

Tags: printing, format, lisp, common-lisp

I am looking for something like:

```
(printem 1 2)
1 2
```

I assume you do this with a format call, but the examples don't focus on this.  Or maybe you write to a string and output that?  But that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: Which Lisp are you talking about?

Comment: Common Lisp is what I am using.

Comment: Why do you put apostrophes `'` before numbers? Non-cons values (atoms) evaluate to themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply build a function that prints all its arguments by the [iteration construct](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cgd.htm) of format.

```
(defun printem (&rest args)
  (format t "~{~a~^ ~}" args))
```

Usage:

```
CL-USER> (printem 1 2 3)
1 2 3
CL-USER> (printem '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
(1 2 3) (4 5 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Common Lisp you can write:

```
(format t "~d ~d~%" 1 2)
```

See [A Few FORMAT Recipes](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html) from Peter Seibel's *Practical Common Lisp* (other chapters might interest you too).

Answer (score 2):

The function you want could be written like

```
(defun printem (&rest args)
    (dolist (el args) 
        (princ el) 
        (princ #\SPACE)))

>> (printem 1 2)
1 2
```